# Sadhya gods from Purusha Sukta vs other references

Tags: rig-veda, brahmanda-purana

In the Purusha Suktam of Rig Veda 10.90 ‘Sadhya Santi devah’ Looks like refers to the Sadhya devas. There are other references to Sadhya devas in several Puranas. The list of Sadhya devas seems to be different in each reference like 12 of Prajapati etc. Do we know of any non-puranical references to Sadhya devas besides Purusha Sukta and their names?

Comment: Do you want the list of Sadhya Devas or just the ref. from other scriptures ?

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn’t mind the list. For e.g Purusha Sukta refers to 7 Sadhya devas.