# The first ones Sadhya Devas responsibilities

Tags: dharma-shastras

Alright, My question here :
[Sadhya gods from Purusha Sukta vs other references](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31912/sadhya-gods-from-purusha-sukta-vs-other-references), still remains unanswered. The motivation for that question is as follows.

Suppose you are a Sadhya Deva, you consult with other Sadhyas. You can compare that to the "Grey council" of Minbaris in Babylon 5 ( See https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Grey_Council). Suppose you run into a very minimal civilization with a fixed set of same sex members. What would be good advice?

1. For procreation
2. Give work for sustenance.

This is very similar to Asuras, Devas and Humans clueless went and stood before Brahma and he said "Da" (Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad) and each of them understood it in their context and proceeded. Do our scriptures or any analysis of the same talk about such things such as Manusmṛti? In a way, that is applied Dharma don't you think? Thanks for your time.